# Making variable volatile in subclass, in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, concurrency, volatile

I've come across the following situation:

```
public class Foo {
    private boolean valid;
        ...
}

public class ConcurrentFoo extends Foo {
        ...
}
```

Since `ConcurrentFoo` is a subclass to be used in a multithreaded environment, as opposed to Foo, which is not *thread-safe*, I'd like `boolean valid` to be, instead, `volatile boolean valid`, **only in the subclass**.

The goal with using `volatile` is to avoid locks and synchronization, since they seem to be unnecessary. There will ever be only two updates to this variable in the lifetime of the object, and lots of (concurrent) reads.

Of course, I could just use synchronization to solve the problem in the subclass, or I could implement it any other way, such that there would be a clearer distinction when using `Foo` and `ConcurrentFoo`. For instance:

```
public class ConcurrentFoo extends Foo {
    // Is this considered shadowing, when adding volatile?
    private volatile boolean valid;
    // Or I could get a completely fresh name.
    private volatile boolean concurrentValid;
}
```

Anyway, **I was curious to know if it is possible to modify non-access modifiers**, such as `volatile` (well, except `final`), **in a subclass**.

**If it isn't possible**, and I think it may not be, unless that shadowing alternative is considered, **what would be the simplest way to overcome this situation?**
Synchronization in the subclass?

Do tell, if more context is needed.
I should note that performance is of some relevance in this case.

Comment: Don't subclass; encapsulate. http://books.google.com/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&lpg=PR1&dq=effective%20java&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false If you want instances of either class to be substitutable, make them implement a common interface.

Comment: The book does say, and I quote, *«(...) It is also safe to use inheritance when extending classes specifically designed and documented for extension (Item 17)»*. I was specifically designing these classes to be extended. However, I do agree that this may be doable without inheritance, and I'll give it a try. Thanks for the book reference, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect not making it volatile is a premature optimization.  If you don't need it to be volatile, but it is made volatile, you are wasting about 3-10 nano-seconds.  If you call this 100 times you are wasting a micro-second (over the life of the component I suspect).  Is this amount of time critical to you?

Comment: Such small amount of time is not critical at all, at least for the use cases I have in mind. This question had more of an *academic* mindset to it. By that, I mean, *if `Foo` assumes it is not going to be concurrent, why having concurrency tools in it? Only the concurrent implementation should worry about it.* But then again, this may be completely wrong, and have a negative impact on the design and implementation.

Comment: In theory, you are right, but to have a pure implementation you end up with something rather ugly and complicated.  The pragmatic solution is to add volatile to Foo.

Comment: Ugly and complicated, indeed. I concur with adding volatile to Foo, in this specific scenario.